# How to let two docker containers can ping each other

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

I have two docker containers A & B, I want to do is in both containers can ping the other container. How should I do? And in one container, what's ip address should I use to ping the other container?

My OS is `ubuntu:14.04`, docker version is `1.6.2`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the ip-address of containers from bridge by using 
"docker network inspect bridge"
then from one container ping the other with the ip address using 
"ping -w3 ip-address"

Answer (score 0):

You can get the container's IP address using:

```
docker inspect -f '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' container1
```

Then just pass this in to the second container somehow, for example:

```
docker exec -it container2 bash -c "echo 1.2.3.4 > pingip"
```

And vice-versa for container2.

You can test using:

```
docker exec -it container2 bash -c "ping \$(cat pingip)"
```

Comment: Yes, containers lose all changes anyways when restarted so you'll need to re-run the commands above.

Comment: Got it. I finally found a tool called weave, it can resolve my problem, thank you.